# Secure WebAPI with ADFS 3 and jscript client

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, adfs

I want to secure my WebAPI service using ADFS 3. [This article](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/) has everything I need except the client is a managed C# application.

In my case the application is a jscript client application running on the browser. I know I could use cookies + ADFS but I rather use token-based authentication if possible.

Is there a way to authenticate against ADFS from jscript?

Comment: Not an easy one, as far as I know you need to build this manually using ADFS authorization end points, so you obtain an authorization code then you exchange it with an access token.